# tensorflow: [NOT FOUND] error in RStudio

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, rstudio

I tried running the following code in `RStudio`:

```
library(tensorflow)

x_data <- runif(100, min=0, max=1)
y_data <- x_data * 0.1 + 0.3

W <- tf$Variable(tf$random_uniform(shape(1L), -1.0, 1.0))
```

But the last line is throwing the following error:

```
Error: Python module tensorflow was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         /usr/bin/python
libpython:      /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib
pythonhome:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
version:        2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]
numpy:          /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
numpy_version:  1.8.1
tensorflow:     [NOT FOUND]
```

This is my first time attempting to incorporate `Python` in `RStudio` (for purposes of accessing Tensorflow), so I'm not sure what I should check (or where) to make sure that my settings are appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that I installed the `python 3` version of `tensorflow` instead of the `python 2` version, which is what my error message was telling me that `RStudio` is using. Using the install instructions found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup#test_the_tensorflow_installation), I installed `tensorflow` on `python 2` and was able to run the above code.

Answer (score 1):

The current CRAN version of the tensorflow package requires you to install the Python tensorflow module first.

The github version has a function, "install_tensorflow()", that tries to do it for you. Try that version.

Note that the python module has pretty strict requirements so this may still fail. Consult the python tensorflow docs in this event.

Comment: thanks. per my answer below, that was the issue...that I didn't have tensorflow installed on the version of Python that RStudio was referencing.