# Tensorflow installation not found in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, rstudio

I am attempting to install tensorflow on R-Studio in Windows 10. I have tried multiple different installation methods (from CRAN, from source, from Conda, from pip)

Each time,  I am told that it installs successfully, but when I try to run the following Hello World command, I get an error (see attached image).

```
library(tensorflow)
tf$constant("Hello World")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn5fy.jpg

Things I have tried:

- [tensorflow: [NOT FOUND] error in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145297/tensorflow-not-found-error-in-rstudio#44145550)
- [Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56010733/error-installation-of-tensorflow-not-found)

Edit 1:

```
> library(tensorflow)
> install_tensorflow()
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

# All requested packages already installed.

Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow==2.0.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.33.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.6.1 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: gast==0.2.2 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorflow-estimator<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.1.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.17.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-applications>=1.0.8 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (42.0.2.post20191203)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: h5py in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow==2.0.0) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.25.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cachetools<3.2,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\zbrass~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.4.8)

Installation complete.


Restarting R session...

> library(tensorflow)
> tf$constant('Hello World')
Error: Python module tensorflow was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:/Users/zbrasseaux/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/zbrasseaux/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/zbrasseaux/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 14:00:49) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/zbrasseaux/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.17.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found a solution at -  https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/

Try:

```
library(tensorflow)

install_tensorflow()
```

Then:

```
library(tensorflow)

tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
```

Comment: I've done this a few times now, after each think I try. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to help anything. I've edited my OP with the output.